# How to make a glass material having a dotted design and lines?

Tags: materials, node-editor, glass

I am new to blender so I don't know much procedural materials. Recently, I started to create a model of my own house in blender and I don't know how to make a glass material look like my window's material. I tried to add roughness to glass but it still having a nice and smooth surface. Rather I want a dotted glass material and with some designing lines. I am sharing an image too. [image]  Please refer picture and help me.

Comment: Looks like you want to familiarize yourself with the usage of "bumpmaps" and "normal maps".

Comment: @haarigertroll Thanks for answering. I do know bump maps and normal maps. But, I never created them. Mostly used normal map in pbr textures which pre-generated by author. So, I am not sure How, I can create a material like this. If you know please share....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that:

[image: Result]

And that's the bump map for it (made in inkscape in less than 5 minutes)

[image: Bumpmap]